# JS: Looking for a fast way to transform points in world to points in screen

Tags: javascript, performance, html

I want to transform a list of points in world coordinates to points in screen (pixels).
Basically I want to multiply a bunch of (worldX, worldY) coordinates in a world to screen matrix.

The problem is that this procedure is very slow.

The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
   worldX = getWorldX(i);
   worldY = getWorldY(i);

   screenX = wtsMat.vx1 * worldX + wtsMat.vy1 * worldY + wtsMat.tx;
   screenY = wtsMat.vx1 * worldX + wtsMat.vy2 * worldY + wtsMat.ty;

  ...
  //Do something with screenX and screenY
}
```

I wonder if there is a better and faster way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Could you give your variables more descriptive names please?

Comment: Where are you using `i`? (Don't you need to index into the world coordinates somehow?)

Comment: seems like screenX/Y do not change during the loop, so why don't you calculate in ahead?

Comment: edited the code. And the variables are very descriptive - world/screen coords ans world to screen (wts) matrix

Comment: Are you sure you should be multiplying your points by the projection matrix? Are you talking about 3d world space to near plane projection?

Comment: no, i am converting 2d to 2d

Answer (score 0):

The wtsMat variables don't change during the loop, so why not define them as variables in stead of properties?

Your code should be something like this:

```
var worldX, worldY, screenX, screenY;
var wtsMatVx1 = wtsMat.vx1;
var wtsMatVy1 = wtsMat.vy1;
var wtsMatTx = wtsMat.tx;
var wtsMatVx2 = wtsMat.vx2;
var wtsMatVy2 = wtsMat.vy2;
var wtsMatTy = wtsMat.ty;
var i = cnt;
for (i; i > 0; i--)
{
    worldX = getWorldX(i);
    worldY = getWorldY(i);

    screenX = wtsMatVx1 * worldX + wtsMatVy1 * worldY + wtsMatTx;
    screenY = wtsMatVx1 * worldX + wtsMatVy2 * worldY + wtsMatTy;

    ...
    //Do something with screenX and screenY
}
```

PS: for calculating `screenY` you use `wtsMat.vx1`, shouldn't this be `wtsMat.vx2`?

Comment: "Clearing" the variables at the end of each loop iteration will have no effect on the calculations and so needlessly slow the loop down. OP is trying to speed it up...

Comment: Doesn't clearing the variables free up memory to be used for other calculations?
If not, then just remove the clearing.

Comment: My point is that immediately after clearing those four variables the next iteration of the loop begins and they get set to other values anyway.

Comment: Updated the post to remove the variable clearing,
also changed the loop from a i++ for-loop to a i-- loop.

This makes a minor performance increase when I test this:
http://jsperf.com/for-or-for

Answer (score 0):

Considering its working I guess the calculations are correct and its just a speed issue.

Also since you left out a part of the code I assume its also slow if you do nothing with sceenX and screenY, so its all in the loop you posted. 
Seeing this is a very simple calculation your cnt must be realy high for it to be slow.

Few things you can do to speed things up:

```
//store object vars locally for quicker access
var wtsMatVx1 = wtsMat.vx1; 
var wtsMatVy1 = wtsMat.vy1; 
var wtsMatVy2 = wtsMat.vy2; 
var wtsMatTx = wtsMat.tx; 
var wtsMatTy = wtsMat.ty; 

while (cnt--)
{
   //while-- is faster according to tests

   var worldX = getWorldX(i); //dont use a global scope, which is used if you dont use var
   var worldY = getWorldY(i); //dont use a global scope


   var screenX = wtsMatVx1 * worldX + wtsMatVy1 * worldY + wtsMatTx;
   var screenY = wtsMatVx1 * worldX + wtsMatVy2 * worldY + wtsMatTy;

  ...
  //Do something with screenX and screenY
}
```